# Can microwave with convection replace an actual oven?

Tags: kitchens, appliances

Maybe this belongs on seasoned advice....

I live in a townhouse with a small kitchen and I am wondering if something like [this KitchenAid item](http://www.kitchenaid.com/shop/major-appliances-1/microwaves-2/microwaves-3/-[KMBP107ESS]-407653/KMBP107ESS/) implies that it can be used as a microwave and as a conventional oven where you would bake things.

I understand the space inside it is limited but as my kitchen is very small if it can serve both roles, that would be a life saver.

Comment: +1 for the Seasoned Advice mention. I think you're right, as they have cooks over there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP cross-posted it to [cooking.se]: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56564/can-microwave-with-convection-replace-an-actual-oven. Please don't cross-post; if you want a question migrated to another site, **and** it belongs there, flag it and ask for it to be moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this could replace an actual oven, because it *is* an actual oven.

According to the specs on the website you linked to, the convection element is completely separate from the microwave element. There is a "microwave mode" and an "oven mode."

The only negative I see is that the heating element is 1600 watts. That's not a lot for that size oven. Toaster ovens typically run 1000W-1500W, and full size ovens run as much as 2400W. That being said, it just means it might take a little longer to warm up. It's not that big of a deal. And with the convection happening, heat will fill the cavity just fine. It just might take a little longer.